# jQuery Validation addMethod - Check if same domain

Tags: jquery, validation, url

I'm trying to check whether a URL is from the same domain with jQuery Validation addMethod.

Here's what i got so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) { 
            return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/testsite.com/.test(value); 
        }, "The URL doesn't match.");

        $("#url_form").validate({
          rules: {
            url: {
              required: true,
              url: true,
              domain : true 
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: Well it seems to be working as it should.

How can i add an options 'www.' in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out. Might be a better way to do, but this worked for me:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) { 
            return this.optional(element) || /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)testsite.com/.test(value); 
        }, "The URL must be on the same Site domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) for all my url's comparison. Might be useful in your case.

Answer (score -1):

I have made a modification on jquery.validade.js, to accept a url without `http://`. Please download it from http://www.tream.com.br/jquery.validate.js.

Usage:

`url: true`

Comment: Is there a source file to this? Minifying it isn't helpful. I was able to find it, but it was ugly.